# How to check whether a variable has a url or an id?

Tags: jquery, url

I am working on a web application, and am using jQuery. I would like to know whether if the `href` variable finds a URL or not using jQuery. How would I do this?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#sections a, #sections_mobile a').click(function(){
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        alert(href);                                                     
    });         
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? questions that show an attempt to solve the problem are more likely to get answers on SO :D

Comment: I want to know the the value in the variable href is a url or not. I can see that the variable has some value but how to find that this value is a url. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  var href = /^(http:|https:)/.test(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
```

Comment: I don't want to check whether variable has a value or not. I want to know that the value in the variable is a url or not. thanks for your reply

Comment: @Rizwi At _"I want to know that the value in the variable is a url or not."_ , what would be limitations of `url` be ? `http:`, `https:` , `data:` could each be a valid `url` ?

Comment: I just want to know if its a url or not. it may be http or https. thanks

Comment: I tested it using   jQuery('#sections a, #sections_mobile a').click(function(){
 var href = /^(http:|https:)/.test(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
       if(href=='true'){
        alert('its url');
       }else { 
        alert('its not url');
        
        }
              
               });   both time it alerts "its not url".

Comment: Try changing to `if (href === true){}` ; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Comment: again same result. every time it says its not url

Comment: Both not not urls ? , can create stacksnippets , jsfiddl;e http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @Rizwi Several of the `href` attributes at http://jsfiddle.net/ycy7ah5y/ do not appear to begin with , include `http:` or `:https` ? Tried clicking `Gallery` link ? Should test include `#` `hash` `href` ?

Comment: The Gallery link has http url. but still showing false

Comment: @Rizwi Clicking "Gallery" appear to alert "its url" at http://jsfiddle.net/ycy7ah5y/2/

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
 jQuery('#sections a, #sections_mobile a').click(function(){
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    if( href.match(/http/).length  )
      alert("Is a url");
    else
      alert("Not url)                                 
 });
```